# Disable the Command-Tab shortcut from Dock

Tags: macos, dock

I have the following problem:
I'm an extensive Quark User since the 90's and recently updated
two of my Macs at work to OSX 10.7.5. I would like to use my favorite Shortcut "Command-Tab" in Quark Xpress as usual, without changing the Apps via
the Dock.

My question: Where can I change or delete this shortcut?

I previous used "Ape" and "PullTab 1.4" to solve my problem, but these hacks are no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F19</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, VK_COMMAND | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::F19, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then remap F19 or shift-F19 in Quark if it is possible.

This would actually disable command-tab and shift-command tab:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, VK_COMMAND | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Lauri, but: These codes disable the shortcuts for the whole Mac OSX and Quark Xpress. What do You mean with "remap F19 ..." in Quark?
Are there other ways to switch between the tools of Quark
as Command-Tab and Command-Alt-Tab?

Comment: @Marcus I have never used Quark, but if there is a menu item for the action performed by command-tab, you can probably change the keyboard shortcut from System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts.